# TSQL values allocation based on existing ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables:

[image: table 1]

[image: table 2]

Using TSQL I have to map the values to the correct ids
example: value 23 between 1 and 100, so the id =A

I am trying the following logic:

**1. I've added an id column to T2:**

```
id=(row_number() over(order by value asc))
```

**2. Declare var:**

```
declare@ as float;  
set value (select value from T2 where id=1)
```

**3. Case to determine if value in range and to exclude other results**

```
select * from   
(  
select   
value=@value  
,a.*  
,test=case  when @value between a.start_range and a.end_range then '1' else'2'   end  
from   
    T1 a  
    )  a  
where   
    a.test=1
```

This works for the first record but, how can this be done when both tables are > 1000 records pe table?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a query yet, and, if so, can you also add this to your question.  Stack Overflow tries to not just be a free code/homework writing service.

Comment: Looks like a pretty straight forward join to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - absolutely, the post is updated accordingly

Comment: @Sean - can you join on something like   join ON a.value between b.start_range and b.end_range? If not I can't see how is a straight join, can you please explain?

Comment: Try it....hint....yes. But I would avoid using between. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: silly me , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
select t.value, tt.id
from table t outer apply (
     select top (1) t1.id
     from table1 t1
     where t.v >= t1.s and t.v <= t1.e
     order by t1.s
) tt
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, a simple join query should work here:

```
SELECT
    t2.value,
    COALESCE(t1.id, 'NA') AS id
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
    ON t2.value BETWEEN t1.[start range] AND t1.[end range];
```

To address the concern raised by @SeanLange, using `BETWEEN` here is not evil, I think, because your ranges appear to be completely non overlapping.  So we can take an inclusive range on both ends, which is the desired behavior.